# Conditionally add items to a list when defining the list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Is there a way to add items to a list conditionally, when defining the list?
Here's what I mean:

```
l = [
    Obj(1),
    Obj(2),
    Separator() if USE_SEPARATORS,
    Obj(3),
    Obj(4),
    Obj(5),
    Separator() if USE_SEPARATORS,
    Obj(6)
]
```

Obviously the above code doesn't work, but is there a similar way?

Currently I have

```
l = [item for item in (
        Obj(1),
        Obj(2),
        Separator() if USE_SEPARATORS,
        Obj(3),
        Obj(4),
        Obj(5),
        Separator() if USE_SEPARATORS,
        Obj(6)
) if not isinstance(item, Separator) or USE_SEPARATORS]
```

But I was wondering if there's an other way that wouldn't required looping through the list, since they can be 10 000 items long and the server stops for a quarter second or so when I execute the code.
It's for a first-person shooter game, so quarter second might actually have an effect on someone dying or living.

Comment: Why are you defining these lists (they look static) at runtime in the function? Why are they not constants to be looked up when needed?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The `Obj` instance's are actually much more complicated, they vary based on the player who calls the function, so they need to be created for every player who joins the server. I'm actually thinking of a different solution than using a list with separators (maybe an ordered dict of lists), but I had this in mind and got curious and wanted to know a good solution, if I were to ever need it. So basically I asked for learning purpose only :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another approach is to use the splat/unpacking operator to expand an element either to the separator or to nothing:

```py
possible_separator = (Separator(),) if USE_SEPARATORS else ()
l = [
    Obj(1),
    Obj(2),
    *possible_separator,
    Obj(3),
    Obj(4),
    Obj(5),
    *possible_separator,
    Obj(6)
]
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd just insert them *afterwards*; lists are mutable after all:

```
l = [
    HeadObj(1),
    HeadObj(2),
    BodyObj(1),
    BodyObj(2),
    BodyObj(3),
    FooterObj(1)
]
if USE_SEPARATORS:
    l.insert(2, Separator())
    l.insert(6, Separator())
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this to anonymous lists, for example, lists that are elements in a greater list, without naming the lists and without accessing the greater list after creation?

Comment: Figured it out, for appending at end (my use case) we can use, for example, `[1, 2, 3] + ([4, 5] if condition else [])`

Comment: This has the drawback that is more difficult to see exactly where in the lust the separators end up, though.

Comment: It's especially hard to tell where the separators end up since each insertion will affect the indices of the subsequent elements.  Inserting separators from tail-to-head probably would be clearer.  Repeated insertions also aren't very efficient, but that wouldn't substantially matter for statically-defined lists like this that are going to be small.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add separators and remove them if not needed:

```
l = [
    Obj(1),
    Obj(2),
    Separator(),
    Obj(3),
    Obj(4),
    Obj(5),
    Separator(),
    Obj(6)]

if not USE_SEPARATORS:
    l = [object for object in l if not isinstance(object, Separator)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [
    Obj(1),
    Obj(2),
    *(Separator() for _i in range(1) if USE_SEPARATORS),
    Obj(3),
    Obj(4),
    Obj(5),
    *(Separator() for _i in range(1) if USE_SEPARATORS),
    Obj(6)
]
```

The idea is to use the list comprehension syntax to construct either a single element list with item 'Separator()', if USE_SEPARATORS is True, or an empty list, if USE_SEPARATORS is False, and then unpack it.

Comment: This doesn't seem substantially different (albeit being a bit more convoluted) than [my much earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62038659/).